# Glinting/gleaming/glimmering/glittering eyes?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, difference

Most dictionaries that I have checked give a definition for the adjectives given in the title when they describe eyes, however it is always something like "When eyes X, they shine in a way that expresses a particular emotion". Therefore, I am wondering if these adjectives have different connotations when they describe eyes, as perceived by a native or some who's studied English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [glint](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/glint+in+your+eyes) or a [gleam](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-gleam-in-your-eye) in somebody's eye means that somebody has a secret- maybe something that amuses you.

A [glimmer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glimmer) is a very dim light, so when it is used about somebody's eye, it maybe means that they barely understand something, or feel only a very slight emotion.

A [glitter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glitter) or [sparkle](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-your-eyes-sparkle) in somebody's eye suggests that they express a strong feeling.